# Any method exists in rails for just modifying the database column without running any before, after save etc methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Any method exists in rails for just modifying the database column without running rails default methods before saving and after saving.

Suppose I have a Model M, and I need to update the M's one column, without calling any methods that Rails usually calls when we saving an Object.

Suppose I have an Object Article and article has a column - published. I want to run only one sql query in the background,

```
update articles set published = 1; 

>> Article.save  # will run all the callbacks and validations

>> Article(:validate => false)  # this only skips validations
```

Is there any way to skip all callbacks and validations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [update_column](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) method

```
article.update_column(:published, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks..for the answer.